# What is the purpose of 9-patch for android? Can I use it for buttons which are in circular shape?

Tags: android

I have an button [like this](http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/visualpharm/icons8-metro-style/128/Arrows-Up-circular-icon.png). I was asked to use 9-patch for android development. I am wondering how 9-patch is useful in this case. I am under impression that 9-patch scaling is for rectangular or squared which are in rounded corners so that even content inside grows the container stretches without the distortion. Please help me understand the actual purpose of the 9-patch scaling for Android. Thanks.

Comment: The NinePatch class permits drawing a bitmap in nine or more sections. Essentially, it allows the creation of custom graphics that will scale the way that you define, when content added within the image exceeds the normal bounds of the graphic..

Answer (score 1):

The content is scalable, the edges will not be scaled, in typical usage.

They're generally used for backgrounds to buttons, or other screen decorations, where the scaled content can be scaled infinitely without losing resolution.

Ideally, they're used in addition to density-dependent resources where appropriate, so that the section of the resource (which you didn't explicitly state is scalable) isn't upscaled and subsequently pixelated.

Consider the splash screen for the Kindle app on Android, which features a silhouette of that boy reading against a tree. In a simplified version, the ground can be scaled horizontally infinitely, but if the boy was scaled, he'd appear skewed. So you could use a nine-patch and specify the section which can be scaled, and in which direction.

That's not enough though - if you only included a low resolution resource, the resource would still be scaled up initially if the device display was of a higher density. In this instance, the boy might look blurred from the upscaling, and is an example of when a higher resolution resource could have helped prevent the pixelation.

The way you've phrased the question suggests (to me) that you're asking whether 9-patch images can replace all drawable resources, like icons or resources with pictures in them, to which the answer is no. They're only to be used to scale sections of resources which feature a block of a single colour (i.e. sections which cannot be pixelated).

--

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch

Comment: So it is similar to Adobe Flash 9 slice scaling. This is not used for graphic buttons which has no text in it?

Answer (score 0):

> Please help me understand the actual purpose of the 9-patch scaling
>   for Android

There are many situations where you find yourself needing the same button style but in different sizes.
So in that case you will have to provide different size resources. But to avoid this, you can simplly provide a 9-patch image, which will be used irrespective of sizes.

Advantages of using 9-patch:

1. When used as background,image won't stretch and loose proportions in different screen sizes.
2. Saves memory.
3. 9-patche images are small, reusable and scale nicely.

If you don' use 9-patch images, you will need to test on various sized screens.

1. [9-Patch](http://9-patch.com/)
2. [A guide to 9-patch](http://radleymarx.com/blog/simple-guide-to-9-patch/)

Comment: For example there is a button image (which has no text in it) with the size of 67x67 (xhdpi) and if I use 9-patch, i don't have to give other 3 resoution images? I just need to filename.9.png to the developers and it will take care of the other 3 resolutions? What is the baseline image size should I provide?

Comment: yes, no need to provide images for different sizes. However, It’s important to note that 9-patch images don’t scale down – they only scale up. So it’s best to start as small as possible.